# Example of new abstract new abstract CreateContainerExtension method in 7.1.0.172-pre

Tags: prism

Does anyone have an example of the new abstract method CreateContainerExtension that is in Prism.Wpf 7.1.0.172-pre? We are using the common service locator and have essentially bypassed IOC in Prism because we need to resolve things before the Bootstrapper has run.

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that Prism is open source and the source code is in itself a form of documentation.

If you're using the classic `Bootstrapper`, you'll notice that it has been deprecated in favor of `PrismApplication`.  Since your question is extremely vague as to what container you're even trying to use, it's impossible to tell exactly which Container Extension to use, but I will provide an example using Unity for your reference.

Whether you look at the [UnityBootstraper](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Unity.Wpf/Legacy/UnityBootstrapper.cs#L199-L202) or the [Unity PrismApplication](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Unity.Wpf/PrismApplication.cs#L14-L17), you'll see that it simply returns an instance of the [UnityContainerExtension](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Unity.Wpf/Ioc/UnityContainerExtension.cs).

```cs
protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
{
    return new UnityContainerExtension();
}
```

Comment: I looked over the source code. Here is the definition: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/5fe0f2d3484bc219e09f70dd798eab06dc1151ec/Source/Prism/Ioc/IContainerExtension.cs and there is not much there to say that there are default extension to use. Searching on ContainerExtension does not turn up much either. There is no MefContainerExtension. As to being vague we use MEF, and we use the bootstrapper and bypass MEF in prism because of timing. I wanted a quick way to disable the feature.

Comment: First of all you're pointing to an interface which is a pure abstraction. Your second comment is the first time that you've mentioned MEF. MEF is NOT a container, and has been discontinued in Prism 7. You are welcome to look at any actual container that we do ship for reference.